# Bootstrap carousel: remove bottom margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

[here's the site](http://s). If you resize the window to a smaller size. You'll notice there's a bottom margin/padding caused by

```
.carousel-inner {
    background-color: #03324c;
}
```

I could remove that but the indicators won't be visible and there will be an empty gap at the bottom . I know that that the images have different size, I tried resizing, same issue. I have tried many things for 2 days, nothing worked.

```
.carousel-inner {
    background-color: #03324c;
}
.carousel-inner img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
    bottom: 0;
}
.carousel-caption h3 {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Do you want the margin to show for the indicators?

Comment: @SamBattat yes im keeping it because it's making the indicators show, that's all i need it for

Comment: Make all the images same width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using a `background-image` combined with `background-size:cover` on the `.item` elements.

For example, your first item would change to this (just remove the `img` tag):

```
<div class="item" style="min-height: 710px;">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>New York</h3>
    <p>The atmosphere in New York is lorem ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the styling for the corresponding `.item` element would be this:

```
.item {
  background-image: url(images/medium/quote.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center; 
}
```

Comment: what are the advantages of that approach?

Comment: You can easily scale the image to fill the space of the container while keeping the proportions of the original image. That being said, you inherently risk having some of the image cut off when you use differently sized images or when the image proportions are very different from the container's proportions

Comment: I don't think the image size is the problem, I think the container is or the indicators are causing the padding

Comment: Neither the container nor the indicators are the problem. The margin you see beneath the `img` comes from the fact that the `img` width is always 100%  of the container, and the `img` height is always auto, meaning it will retain the original proportions. So then what will happen when the container exhibits a dimensions with a height that is taller than the `img`'s original dimensions? The `img`, of course, will have to be shorter than the container, which is where the "margin" on the bottom comes from. It's not actually a CSS margin - it's just space that's not being filled by the `img`.

Answer (score 0):

@feihcism, I immediately agree with your comment, then I had to make the image 100% whatever its parent is and believe me. it works

```
.carousel-item img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit:cover;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%; // I mean this!
}
```